# Compose URL for webView

Tags: url, xamarin

I have a webView in xamarin called Browser and I should give it a URL.

```
        string ciao = "pizza";
        Browser.Source = "www." + pizza + ".it";
```

I have this code, how can I compose the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Uri` class.

```
string ciao = "pizza";
string it = "it";
Browser.Source = new Uri (string.Format ("http://www.{0}.{1}",ciao,it));
```

Answer (score 1):

a URL needs a protocol

```
Source = $"http://www.{ciao}.com"
```